# Slicing fasta file

Tags: python, fasta

Help me,

I have a fasta file I want to apply some operations on it.I suppose that my file contains 500 sequences, and `for i=1 to 500` I want to take three sequences and apply some functions, so I will do the same operations in 166 times, each time I take 3 sequences

```
for i=1 to 500 do (500 number of sequences in fasta file)

take 3 sequences

    apply some functions
```

**Example:**
My file contains 9 sequences

```
   1-tatctattaccc

   2-gctgcgataagc

   3-tcctacttttgt

   4-caggaaaagaaa

   5-actgaatccctt

   6-ctgaagttgact

   7-aggtttgaagtg

   8-aacttccaactc

   9-gaaaagcaccct
```

I take the first 3 sequences

```
       seq1-tatctattaccc

       seq2-gctgcgataagc

       seq3-tcctacttttgt
```

I apply some functions,then, I take sequences number 4,5,6,I do the same thing as the sequences number 1,2,3 then i do the same thing with 7,8,9
**This is my function**:

```
def identical(input_string):
code={"a":0,"c":1,"g":2,"t":3}
p=[code[i] for i in input_string]
n=len(input_string)
c=0
for i, n in enumerate(range(n, 0, -1)):
    c +=p[i]*(4**(n-1))
    return c+1
```

My function must  use only this:{"a","c","g","t"}, but In fasta file sequence start with **'>'**,like this:

```
>gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene and ITS1 and ITS2 DNA
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
CCGCCTCGGGAGCGTCCATGGCGGGTTTGAACCTCTAGCCCGGCGCAGTTTGGGCGCCAAGCCATATGAA
AGCATCACCGGCGAATGGCATTGTCTTCCCCAAAACCCGGAGCGGCGGCGTGCTGTCGCGTGCCCAATGA
ATTTTGATGACTCTCGCAAACGGGAATCTTGGCTCTTTGCATCGGATGGAAGGACGCAGCGAAATGCGAT
AAGTGGTGTGAATTGCAAGATCCCGTGAACCATCGAGTCTTTTGAACGCAAGTTGCGCCCGAGGCCATCA
GGCTAAGGGCACGCCTGCTTGGGCGTCGCGCTTCGTCTCTCTCCTGCCAATGCTTGCCCGGCATACAGCC
AGGCCGGCGTGGTGCGGATGTGAAAGATTGGCCCCTTGTGCCTAGGTGCGGCGGGTCCAAGAGCTGGTGT
TTTGATGGCCCGGAACCCGGCAAGAGGTGGACGGATGCTGGCAGCAGCTGCCGTGCGAATCCCCCATGTT
GTCGTGCTTGTCGGACAGGCAGGAGAACCCTTCCGAACCCCAATGGAGGGCGGTTGACCGCCATTCGGAT
GTGACCCCAGGTCAGGCGGGGGCACCCGCTGAGTTTACGC

>gi|2765657|emb|Z78532.1|CCZ78532 C.californicum 5.8S rRNA gene and ITS1 and ITS2 DNA
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGTTGAGACAACAGAATATATGATCGAGTG
AATCTGGAGGACCTGTGGTAACTCAGCTCGTCGTGGCACTGCTTTTGTCGTGACCCTGCTTTGTTGTTGG
GCCTCCTCAAGAGCTTTCATGGCAGGTTTGAACTTTAGTACGGTGCAGTTTGCGCCAAGTCATATAAAGC
ATCACTGATGAATGACATTATTGTCAGAAAAAATCAGAGGGGCAGTATGCTACTGAGCATGCCAGTGAAT
TTTTATGACTCTCGCAACGGATATCTTGGCTCTAACATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCTAAATGCGATAAGTGG
TGTGAATTGCAGAATCCCGTGAACCATCGAGTCTTTGAACGCAAGTTGCGCTCGAGGCCATCAGGCTAAG
GGCACGCCTGCCTGGGCGTCGTGTGTTGCGTCTCTCCTACCAATGCTTGCTTGGCATATCGCTAAGCTGG
CATTATACGGATGTGAATGATTGGCCCCTTGTGCCTAGGTGCGGTGGGTCTAAGGATTGTTGCTTTGATG
GGTAGGAATGTGGCACGAGGTGGAGAATGCTAACAGTCATAAGGCTGCTATTTGAATCCCCCATGTTGTT
GTATTTTTTCGAACCTACACAAGAACCTAATTGAACCCCAATGGAGCTAAAATAACCATTGGGCAGTTGA
TTTCCATTCAGATGCGACCCCAGGTCAGGCGGGGCCACCCGCTGAGTTGAGGC
```

So,

```
if line=='>' then  pass
```

ie: lines like :`>gi|2765657|emb|Z78532.1|CCZ78532 C.californicum 5.8S rRNA gene and ITS1 and ITS2 DNA` must be ignored
When I use my function, it gives this  error :

```
KeyError: '>'
```

or  error like: `KeyError: 'CGT'`

How can I do it?

Comment: If you want to respond to someone's answer, you should post a comment, rather than edit their post

Comment: Which part of the line is the A/T/C/G that you want to pay attention to?

Comment: ok, this is sequence:`>gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene and ITS1 and ITS2 DNA
**CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTGAATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTG**`, for me, the I want to pay attention to all bases between stars

Comment: Like I mentioned in response to your comment on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17903304/198633), there is a severe lack of formatting in the comments box. Please edit you post to include one full, representative line from your fasta file and indicate which portion of it you'd like to extract.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    while True:
        line1 = f.readline()
        line2 = f.readline()
        line3 = f.readline()
        if not line3:
            break
        doSomething(line1, line2, line3)
```

Comment: thank you, between my operation there is function witch return an integer, in my file there is lines like this:>gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene and ITS1 and ITS2, which indicate the sequence, for me *I must ignore  this part, because it gives error with the **'>'** and **'|'**  when I use the function

Answer (score 1):

On python 2.x:

```
import itertools
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for seq1, seq2, seq3 in itertools.izip(infile, infile, infile):
        do_something(seq1, seq2, seq3)
```

The reason I use `itertools.izip` over the usual `zip` is because in python 2.x, `zip` returns a list, which you then iterate over. `itertools.izip` on the other hand, iterates over the appropriate elements without creating a list in the first place. This saves on memory usage, as well as the time it takes to allocate memory for, and create the list.

On python 3.x, the built-in `zip` functions exactly as `itertools.izip` does in python 2.x (to get python 2.x's `zip` functionality in python 3.x, you'll need to do `L = list(zip(…))`):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for seq1, seq2, seq3 in zip(infile, infile, infile):
        do_something(seq1, seq2, seq3)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: with open('path/to/file') as infile:
        for seq1, seq2, seq3 in zip(infile, infile, infile):
        do_something(seq1, seq2, seq3), Here I have to use function which return integer , but my sequences starts with **>'**

Comment: yes, this is my function:`def a(input_string):
 code={"a":0,"c":1,"g":2,"t":3}
 p=[code[i] for i in input_string]
 n=len(input_string)
 c=0
 for i, n in enumerate(range(n, 0, -1)):
  c +=p[i]*(4**(n-1))
  return c+1`,

Comment: @m28: you need to edit this function into your original post, along with what the error is. The comment is not specific enough by itself

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import itertools

with open('/tmp/lines.txt', 'rU') as fasta:
    data=itertools.izip_longest(*[fasta]*3)
```

That has the advantage of delivering all the lines even if the number lines may not be a multiple of 3. The remainder of the last tuple (either 0, 1 or 2 of the last tuple) are filled with `None`. You would want to have `something()` anticipate that.

Or, if you want to expand into three variables:

```
with open('/tmp/lines.txt', 'rU') as fasta:
    for a,b,c in itertools.izip_longest(*[fasta]*3):
        something(a,b,c)
```

Note that since izip_longest completes tuples if the number of lines in the file is not a integer multiple of 3 with `None` you might have `c` or `b, c` as `None`. Just test for that or throw away the last tuple if incomplete.

If you know you would not use the last tuple if incomplete, use this:

```
with open('/tmp/lines.txt', 'rU') as fasta:
    for a,b,c in itertools.izip(*[fasta]*3):
        something(a,b,c)
```

Comment: fair point. I guess I was looking at a pre-edit version of your post. Withdrawn

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way of dealing with fasta sequences in python is always using Biopython. Ii could be a little tricky at the beginning but it worth the effort.

First of all you should install biopython. Just type in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-biopython
```

Now you have an incredible fasta parser in python!

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
```

So you can now iterate over records (sequences) and retrieve independently their id, description, sequence, alphabet, get the reverse complement, etc.

```
with open("your_fasta_file.fasta", "r") as infh:
    parser = SeqIO.parse(infh, "fasta")
```

Now you have "parser" of your fasta file, which is an iterator you can use in a loop:

```
for sequence in parser:
    do stuff with sequence.id 
    do stuff with str(sequence.seq) # See below why str(seq)
    do stuff with sequence.description
```

For a record like ">gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene and ITS1 and ITS2"

sequence.id --> would be something like "gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|"

sequence.description --> would be the entire header ">gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene and ITS1 and ITS2"

sequence.seq --> would be the sequence. You have to take care at this point because sequence.seq returns a Seq object: Seq('AGCTAGTAGCTG... ATGAC', Alphabet())

If you want to take the sequence as a normal string simply use:

```
str(Seq_object)
```